# jquery wait all content is loaded (include img)

Tags: jquery, function, load, wait

I have a script that allows to load some content from a page and I want to execute some stuff only when all the content is completely loaded.

I tried with this script but it doesn't seem to be enough in IE:

```
$(".ajaxify_container").load('single.php?page='+url.substring(1)+' #single-container', null, function(){
    $(".Slide img").on("load", function () { 
        load_content_animation();
    });
})
```

Answer (score 1):

### **Edit - 1**

```
var $images = $(".Slide img"), imageCount = $images.length;
var counter;

$(".Slide img").on("load", function () { 
   counter++;
   if (counter == imageCount) {
       load_content_animation();
   }
});
```

### **Original**

> I want to execute some stuff only when all the content is completely
>   loaded.

Use `window load`. This will execute once everything is downloaded.

```
jQuery(window).load(function () {
   //Your code comes here
});
```

Comment: thank you but it can't work like this with loaded content because it's already fire on window load...

Comment: @freaky : as you said **I want to execute some stuff only when all the content is completely loaded.**

Comment: it don't works because for shure. This is because I use pushstate or hashchange function...

Comment: @freaky : What is the html for `ajaxify_container` ?

Comment: I think I found my problem. I just realize that `$(".Slide img").on("load", function () {` is triggered every time an img is loaded. So it triggers each time my slider function. I need to execute my animation function after all img loaded, not after each...

Comment: @freaky : That's the reason you should use `window load`

Comment: window load don't works! That's normal because the loaded content is trigger after an pushstate or hashchange method. I need to implement a counter in `$(".Slide img").on("load", function ()` and it will works great I think...

Comment: Your counter script is wrong, you need to declare your counter variable before to increment. But my counter doesn't solve completely the problem, it's better but not perfect... Thank you for your help

Answer (score -1):

Wrap the content you want hidden until the page loads with a div:

```
<div class="hide">
    <!-- Content hidden when page is loading -->
</div>
```

Hide the content with CSS:

```
.hide {
    display: none;
}
```

Then use JQuery to hide and show the content:

```
jQuery(window).load(function() {
    $('.loading').fadeOut(1000);
    $('.hide').show();
});
```

Comment: Thank you but I can't do this... I want to really wait all img are loaded because I want to initialize a slider only if all image are loaded. If I don't do this my website freeze...

Comment: @freaky This will do exactly that, place wrap your slider with a DIV to hide it and it's images and the slider won't show until the page is completely loaded, with all the images.

Comment: I know this kind of trick but in my case it can't work..it's impossible because it's loaded thanks to history pushstate or to hashchange and this function works already with window.load